# How to filter an array of object inside an array of objects based on an array and also remove properties of that object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let array1= [
    { "id": 100, name: "A", "details": [{"year": "2012"},{"data": "Test1"}]},
    { "id": 101, name: "B", "details": [{"year": "2013"},{"data": "Test2"}]},
    { "id": 102, name: "C", "details": [{"year": "2014"},{"data": "Test3"}]}
];

const array2= ['2012'];
```

Result I wanted

```
{ "id": 100, name: "A", "details": [{"year": "2012"}]}
```

I know i can filter the array with this code

```
array1.filter(o => 
  o.details.some(p=> {
    return array2.includes(p.year)
  })
)
```

But is there a way to remove the objects as well.

Comment: Simply assign the result of the `.filter` into the variable `array1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reduce to avoid multiple steps

This reduce filters and deletes part of the details array

```js
let array1 = [
    { "id": 100, name: "A", "details": [{"year": "2012"},{"data": "Test1"}]},
    { "id": 101, name: "B", "details": [{"year": "2013"},{"data": "Test2"}]},
    { "id": 102, name: "C", "details": [{"year": "2014"},{"data": "Test3"}]}
];

const array2 = ['2012'];

let array3 = array1.reduce((acc, {id,name,details}) => {
  if (array2.includes(details[0].year)) {
    acc.push({ id, name, details: details[0] })
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(array3)
```

Comment: Ok..is there a way to remove the other objects as well..like{ "data": "Test1" } when applying the filter.

Comment: See update using reduce